# How to place "Power On" indicator lights?

Tags: led, batteries, indicator

I'm working on a replacement board for an old system. I have two terminal blocks.

- Terminal Block 1 (left) is the input from the power supply to the board. This is the primary power supply to the board and rest of the circuit. Pin1 = +, Pin2= -, Pin3 = -.
- Terminal Block 2 (right) is the input from the battery and charger. [Battery
  Charger datasheet](http://www.altechcorp.com/power/PDFs/PS-UPS40.pdf) The battery system is to come into use if the power from the factory was to go out. Pin1 = +, Pin2= -, Pin3 = -.

Here's my schematic I'm working on at the moment. [image: Close up]

Is this the correct way to add indicator lights to the inputs? I want to be able to tell when the board is receiving power (INPUT) from the power supply and when the Battery is in use. I'm pretty sure that the Battery LED (BATT) is going to be on all the time since it's being powered from the input. Is there a way to single this out?

I was going to initially put the resistor and LED in line with the "+" trace on both circuits, but I don't know if that's would effect the charging circuit on Terminal 2.

D1 is to protect against backwards connection to the power supply. Can I place one at the same location for the battery supply? Will this effect the recharging ability?

Edit: "Truth Table"

- INPUT LED - On when Terminal 1 is supplying power (IE outside system, such as a factory main line, is able to provide power). Off when outside system is loses power.
- BATT LED - On when the battery is used to power the system (IE power from Terminal 1 is no longer being supplied and the system needs to run off a battery). Preferably off when Terminal 1 is in use.

Edit 2 - Full Circuit [image: Full Circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post is a little garbled and a block diagram of your setup (use the built-in schematic editor) would be a big help. I don't think your wiring scheme is correct.

[image: Altech UPS]

*Figure 1. UPS block diagram from [AltechCorp.com](http://www.altechcorp.com/power/PDFs/PS-UPS40.pdf).*

- The UPS + and - terminals are both 24 V DC input (while mains power is on) and output when mains power has failed.
- The power supply shown in Figure 1 should be 24 V DC nominal.

Indicator lamps can be wired from the 'DC OK', 'BAT FAIL' AND 'BAT DISCHARGE' relay contacts.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdeQVv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. LED indicator schematic.*

How it works

Let's assume that the mains power supply is giving out 24 V.

- D1 provides a 0.5 V drop. (See [BAS70 datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BAS70_1PS7XSB70_SER.pdf) page 7).
- When mains is on D2 lights with 24 V on the anode and about 24 - 0.7 (D4) - 2 (D2) = 21.3 V on the cathode. Because of the three two diodes in its circuit D3's anode voltage will be lower than D2's and will glow dimly if at all.
- When mains fails D2 turns off and D3 will now light.
- D4 is required to protect D2 from high-voltage reverse bias.
- D5 is required to give the same voltage drop as D4.
- D6 ensures that the voltage difference between the two LEDs is high enough to work as intended.

I haven't tested this.

Comment: Unfortunately the DC OK, BAT Fail, and Bat discharge LED's only come on when the system is discharging more than 2A. Our system will almost never discharge this much current so they're pretty much useless to us.

Comment: Please edit your post and add a truth table showing which lights should come on and when.

Comment: Figured a truth table was a little more than needed. Added a description for the LED's.

Comment: See update showing possible solution.

Comment: @transistor Minor quibble - the original circuit shows a schottky diode, while yours uses an ordinary rectifier diode.  But adding the extra diode before D3 would work even with a schottky diode for D1.

Comment: Very nice idea @transistor. This is what I was looking for. I'll breadboard it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @transistor - Just in case you were losing sleep over your design, I bread boarded it out and it works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Thank you for the feedback and the 'accept'.

Answer (score 0):

The PWR LED will work as you require.

The PWR1 LED will light all the time that either the power is on **or** the battery is powering the circuit.  So it it's basically just an "on" light.

If you added a second diode as in the Input line, then it still wouldn't really help.  First, the PWR1 LED would still be on all the time that the battery was charged (whether or not it was powering the circuit), and second it would stop the battery from ever charging.

Comment: Is there any way to have the PWR1 LED on only when the battery system is discharging? That's where I got stuck is trying to single out that LED without blocking the boards charging ability.

Comment: @Luke I'm struggling to think of anything that would work. Have you thought about changing the labels on the LEDs?

Comment: I've replaced the images.

Comment: @Luke I really meant change the labels on the equipment itself to say what the LEDs actually indicate, not what you wanted them to indicate.  It was a semi-serious work-around, rather than the solution to your problem.

Comment: I see. Ha! But that was my next idea if I couldn't think of a different way.